# How to configure IPython session using start_ipython()?

Tags: ipython

I have some code that launches an IPython session using `start_ipython`.  It accepts a `config` option allowing to pass in a `Config()` object.

I can do things like:

```
c = Config()
c.InteractiveShellEmbed.colors = args.color
c.InteractiveShell.confirm_exit = args.confirmexit
c.InteractiveShell.prompts_class = MyPrompt
c.InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = 'last_expr_or_assign'

IPython.start_ipython(config=c, user_ns=globals())
```

which changes prompts and display behaviour.  All good.

I also wish to set some of the default formatters.  The following works once I am in IPython

```
plain = get_ipython().display_formatter.formatters['text/plain']
plain.for_type(np.float64, plain.lookup_by_type(float))
```

but I want to set this up before launching IPython.  The config object has a `DisplayFormatter` attribute but I don't understand how to configure it.

An ugly workaround is

```
code = [
    "plain = get_ipython().display_formatter.formatters['text/plain'];",
    "plain.for_type(np.float64, plain.lookup_by_type(float));",
    "precision('%.3g');"
       ]
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = code
IPython.start_ipython(config=c, user_ns=globals())
```

which does the trick but the IPython session starts with

```
Out[1]: <function IPython.core.formatters.PlainTextFormatter._type_printers_default.<locals>.<lambda>(obj, p, cycle)>
Out[1]: "('%.3g');"
```

which I'd prefer not to see (and despite semicolons on the ends of the lines).

I want to avoid the need to change any external configuration files, so that IPython works for the user out of the box with specific behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The formatter classes are configurable as well.

Passing the type to formatter func dict might work for you. Refer https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html#configtrait-BaseFormatter.type_printers.

PlainTextFormatter also has an option to set the precision. Refer
https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html#configtrait-PlainTextFormatter.float_precision

Update #1:

```py
c.PlainTextFormatter.float_precision = "%.3f"
c.BaseFormatter.type_printers = {np.float64: lambda obj, *args: str("%.3f" % obj)}
```

Comment: How do I get to the BaseFormatter or PlainTextFormatter?

Comment: Similar to how you configured InteractiveShellEmbed.colors and others, configure BaseFormatter.type_printers and PlainTextFormatter.float_precision

Comment: Thanks for your help, but precision doesn't change
>>> 1.234234234234242342
gives 1.2342342342342423
and printing a float64 gives me a big traceback

Comment: Ipython version?

Comment: Let's say I just do the first two lines of your update, then all is good.  The third line messes precision for float, and stack traces for float64

Comment: Error comes from the lambda, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'Unicode' and 'float'.  This looks like old style formatting syntax, but I'm guessing float_format not a string

Comment: IPython is 7.19.0

Comment: Don't know who downgraded the answer, not me, I think we're on a roll

Comment: If you're specifying the precision in the format string you can hardcode it for np.float64 as well. Try the updated code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230836/discussion-between-peter-corke-and-crash0v3rrid3).